# word caption doesn't allow selection of new style

Tags: ms-word

I am trying to add an appendix to my word document, and I'd like my figure numbering to restart with the appendix. I have set up a multi level list where I have an Appendix chapter heading (image a) and I have a style set up for this heading (image b). But, I can't tell the figure reference to find this style (image c), and therefore I get an error in the caption (image d). How can I fix this / use a work around?

[image: Image A]

Image A: multi-level list resets after my level 1 list, so it starts after my last chapter.

[image: Image B]

Image B: it is linked to a new heading style called "Heading 1: Appendix"

[image: Image C]

Image C: I can only reference it to Heading 1-9; my new style "Heading 1: Appendix" does not come up as an option

[image: Image D]

Image D: If I set it to Heading 1, then all the figures start with my last Chapter number (5). So it's just broken.

Comment: You did a great job writing your question, but this is a programming forum, not a Word forum. Your question is ***off-topic*** here and likely will be closed without answers. The confusion is understandable. https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic  This would be an appropriate question on the **Microsoft Community** http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/msoffice_word or on **Super User** https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/microsoft-word or other forums. If you do post something there, you should delete this question or add a link here  to the new question there to help others.

Comment: see http://shaunakelly.com/word/numbering/numberingappendixes.html and https://www.addbalance.com/usersguide/10HeadingStyles.htm